# Cause: null value in entry: aaptFriendlyManifestOutputDirectory=null

Tags: android

I made a android project few days ago ! Now when I'm running that project it is show this error.

> Cause: null value in entry: aaptFriendlyManifestOutputDirectory=null

[image: Here is picture]

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error was resolved after deleting the `.gradle` folder, then rebuilding project.

Comment: @janpio I did not get you.

Comment: I just left a comment to tell people that this didn't just work for you, but for me as well.

Comment: If you put `I` at start of your comment, then I did not ask that. starting from `Can` make this a question.

Comment: Well, I would have used a question mark if it were a question.